# Using Buildbot, how do I change "shell_1" to something else?

Tags: buildbot

Before my build starts, each of my `ShellCommand` steps are labelled `shell_\d+`. It would be nice if Buildbot used the step `description` instead of the auto generated shell label. Also when we get an email notification, as it says `BUILD FAILED: failed shell_3` but it would be nicer if it said `BUILD FAILED: unit test xyz failed`.

Is there a way to change this shell ID id something else? Perhaps by creating a custom build step and overriding a function? I'm not sure where this ID comes from exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You give the step a name in the addStep method for example:

```
f = buildbot.process.factory.BuildFactory()
f.addStep(buildbot.steps.shell.ShellCommand((name = 'Hello',
                                             cmd = ['echo', 'Hello World']))
```

I'd implement the second part as a [log observer](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/customization.html#adding-logobservers)

Comment: Yep, `name` works, brilliant! I'm sure I tried this already, oh well.